# Minus qty in stock level even though no backorders is set to No

Tags: stock, inventory, quantity

As per the subject, in the *Configuration Inventory options*, I have set the option for Backorders to **"No Backorders"**.  However, I'm still seeing minus figures appearing for some products.  Can't work out what is causing this?

Looking at example products, **the option in Inventory is also set to No Backorders**.  The products are correctly set to out of stock (the option is set to be out of stock if quantity is 0) but they just seem to have minus figures.

Any ideas?

Manoj

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is happening due to orders placed in the backend.  When you add an item to the order, even if it gives a warning message (out of stock, or will go out of stock), it seems that the order can still be placed.